# Dialog closing due to DataGrid rerender after RTKQuery tag invalidates

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

So as I was writing out the question, I had a thought and found a solution. I'm still posting this for anyone who needs it, I came across some similar posts along this topic without an answer.

**Original Problem:**

I have a Mui DataGrid that fetches data through RTK Query- with the call I usually use an option that provides a tag which a mutation (e.g. post/patch/delete call) can invalidate, triggering a refetching of the data (which rerenders the DataGrid to reflect the changes).

Each row of the DataGrid has an action button, which opens a dialog which itself contains an action to approve the DataGrid item(this is the action that invalidates the tag on the original fetch). When the item is approved, the DataGrid rerenders and the Dialog is closed with it. This makes sense since the Dialog is rendered through the button click of an item that is no longer on the DataGrid list so it is not rendered. However, I want to leave the Dialog open to provide some options (that are themselves dependent on the approve step).

My first work around was not providing a tag and using the refetch method that comes with the query hook, and this allows for the initial functionality I mentioned above. However, the only downside was that now the DataGrid query will not refetch if a change is made elsewhere in the app that affects the same data. In my example, the query is pulling any reports that are submitted and need to be approved. So at that point, I could prevent the closing of the dialog, at the expense of the DataGrid component's query not knowing to refetch if a change is made deeper in the app, unless I had a button for the user to manually call the refetch, which was not desirable.

**The Solution:**

RTK query also has a refetchOnMountOrArgChange prop that can be supplied to the query. For my use case, this means that when the user leaves the particular page, does some other stuff, and comes back to the page with the query, it will refetch and reflect any new data. One point I had to figure out, the prop needed to come as a second argument, like this:
const {data, refetch} = useFetchDataQuery({}, {refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true})

When I first implemented without the initial blank {}, it did not register.

I gotta say, I really do appreciate the flexibility of RTK Query, and heres the docs on refetching for anyone who needs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#manipulating-cache-behavior

In case anyone needs some example code to look at:

DataGrid:

```
const GridDisplay = () => {
   const {data, refetch} = useFetchDataQuery({}, {refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true}); 
//RTKQuery call that can set a tag when data fetched, the refetchOnMountOrArgChange forced a refetch when the component mounts

   const columns = [
     ...
     {
       field: 'actions',
       headerName: '',
       width: 80,
       renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                    <ApprovePlan props={props} refetch={refetch} /> //passing the refetch method as a prop to child
                )
            }
     }
...
}
```

Dialog:

```
const ApprovePlan = ({props, refetch}) => {
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  
   const handleClickOpen = () =? {
    setOpen(true)
   }

  const handleClose = () => {
     refetch(); //call the refetch method on child dialog close
     setOpen(false);
   }
   ...
   return (
   ...
  {props.approved === false ? (
      <ApproveStepModal  props={props} /> //action that can invalidate tag causing refetch
                                          // and also causing modal to close
   ):(
   <DoOtherStuffButtons />
  }
```